# ionic 4 Class not found error using native storage

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

I can't tell why native storage is failing. I have a service that implements it like so:-

```
constructor( private store: NativeStorage) {
    //
}
```

Then calling:

```
this.store.getItem(key)
```

For this I get an error:
[image]

Comment: Also getting this error at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this error by removing and adding android platform.

1. `ionic cordova platform remove android`
2. `ionic cordova platform add android`

After that I got these warnings.
[image]

I followed the instructions in the terminal by running

1. `npm i -g cordova-res`
2. `ionic cordova resources android --force`

When everything was done I reinstalled my app on my android device by using this command: `ionic cordova run android --device -l --debug`